# JWT authentication from Unity script

Tags: c#, authentication, unity-game-engine, jwt

I'm trying to write a simple Unity script that will authenticate with my server using JWT. Unfortunately I can't use the .NET plugin for JWT as it requires a newer version of .NET than what Unity uses (Mono thing). So I've tried to write it myself. I can manage to perform the login, but I can't seem to work out how to use the idToken afterwards. This is what I've got:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using UnityEngine;

public class JsonLoaderTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static string BASE_HTTP_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";
    public static string BASE_HTTPS_URL = "https://localhost:8080/";

    private string _idToken = "";

    // Use this for initialization
    [UsedImplicitly]
    IEnumerator Start () {
        yield return StartCoroutine(GetBeers());
        yield return StartCoroutine(Login());
        yield return StartCoroutine(GetBeers());
    }

    private IEnumerator GetBeers()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _idToken);
        WWW www = new WWW(BASE_HTTP_URL + "api/beers", null, headers);
        while (!www.isDone) yield return null;
        Debug.Log(www.text);
    }

    public class LoginPackage
    {
        public string username;
        public string password;
        public bool rememberMe;
    }

    public class IdTokenPackage
    {
        public string idToken;
    }

    private IEnumerator Login()
    {
        LoginPackage loginPackage = new LoginPackage();
        loginPackage.username =  "admin";
        loginPackage.password = "admin";
        loginPackage.rememberMe = true;

        Dictionary<string, string> postHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        postHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(loginPackage);
        byte[] postData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        WWW www = new WWW(BASE_HTTP_URL + "api/authenticate", postData, postHeaders);
        while (!www.isDone) yield return null;
        Debug.Log(www.text);
        _idToken = JsonUtility.FromJson<IdTokenPackage>(www.text).idToken;
    }
}
```

As you'd expect the first "GetBeers" request fails with a 401, as I haven't got an ID token. The login works and returns an idToken, but when I try to make the second "GetBeers" request, now with a non-empty ID, it's still failing with a 401. This is the log on the server:

```
2017-09-25 21:32:39.904 DEBUG 9968 --- [ XNIO-2 task-16] c.s.beerapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect    : Enter: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Sep 25 21:32:39 CEST 2017, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]]
2017-09-25 21:32:39.907 DEBUG 9968 --- [ XNIO-2 task-16] c.s.beerapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect    : Exit: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with result = null
2017-09-25 21:32:39.909 DEBUG 9968 --- [ XNIO-2 task-16] i.g.j.s.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint    : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2017-09-25 21:32:40.145 DEBUG 9968 --- [ XNIO-2 task-25] c.s.beerapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect    : Enter: com.svendhhh.beerapp.web.rest.UserJWTController.authorize() with argument[s] = [LoginVM{username='admin', rememberMe=true}, com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter$StatusExposingServletResponse@7f7712]
2017-09-25 21:32:40.146 DEBUG 9968 --- [ XNIO-2 task-25] c.s.b.security.DomainUserDetailsService  : Authenticating admin
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_7_0_, authority2_.name as name1_4_1_, user0_.created_by as created_2_7_0_, user0_.created_date as created_3_7_0_, user0_.last_modified_by as last_mod4_7_0_, user0_.last_modified_date as last_mod5_7_0_, user0_.activated as activate6_7_0_, user0_.activation_key as activati7_7_0_, user0_.email as email8_7_0_, user0_.first_name as first_na9_7_0_, user0_.image_url as image_u10_7_0_, user0_.lang_key as lang_ke11_7_0_, user0_.last_name as last_na12_7_0_, user0_.login as login13_7_0_, user0_.password_hash as passwor14_7_0_, user0_.reset_date as reset_d15_7_0_, user0_.reset_key as reset_k16_7_0_, authoritie1_.user_id as user_id1_8_0__, authoritie1_.authority_name as authorit2_8_0__ from jhi_user user0_ left outer join jhi_user_authority authoritie1_ on user0_.id=authoritie1_.user_id left outer join jhi_authority authority2_ on authoritie1_.authority_name=authority2_.name where user0_.login=?
2017-09-25 21:32:40.237 DEBUG 9968 --- [ XNIO-2 task-25] c.s.beerapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect    : Enter: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Sep 25 21:32:40 CEST 2017, principal=admin, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={}]]
Hibernate: insert into jhi_persistent_audit_event (event_id, event_date, event_type, principal) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
2017-09-25 21:32:40.240 DEBUG 9968 --- [ XNIO-2 task-25] c.s.beerapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect    : Exit: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with result = null
2017-09-25 21:32:40.242 DEBUG 9968 --- [ XNIO-2 task-25] c.s.beerapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect    : Exit: com.svendhhh.beerapp.web.rest.UserJWTController.authorize() with result = <200 OK,com.svendhhh.beerapp.web.rest.UserJWTController$JWTToken@566d9495,{}>
2017-09-25 21:32:40.257 DEBUG 9968 --- [ XNIO-2 task-24] c.s.beerapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect    : Enter: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Sep 25 21:32:40 CEST 2017, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]]
2017-09-25 21:32:40.258 DEBUG 9968 --- [ XNIO-2 task-24] c.s.beerapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect    : Exit: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with result = null
2017-09-25 21:32:40.260 DEBUG 9968 --- [ XNIO-2 task-24] i.g.j.s.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint    : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong? Am I including the authentication header in the wrong way/format?

Comment: Oh, I can see now the problem is with my deserialisation of the returned JSON. I'm not getting the `id-token` value out into the `idToken` field of my `IdTokenPackage` class...

Comment: ...However, I can't work out why not. I thought maybe it was because I was missing a `[Serializable]` tag, but that didn't help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the name of the variable in my `IdTokenPackage` class. I had read the value in the json as `id-token`, and assumed this would be serialised as `idToken` (as you can't have dashes in c# variable names). However, the actual name in the json was `id_token`, and I had to change the name in the C# class correspondingly:

```
public class IdTokenPackage
{
    public string id_token;
}
```

It does mean that my problem wasn't exactly to do with JWT, but at least then maybe someone can find the script useful if their implementing JWT authentication from Unity themselves.